# How can I select multiple columns from a subquery (in SQL Server) that should have one record (select top 1) for each record in the main query?

Tags: sql

I Know I can select a column from a subquery using this syntax:

```
SELECT A.SalesOrderID, A.OrderDate,
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 B.Foo
       FROM B
       WHERE A.SalesOrderID = B.SalesOrderID
       ) AS FooFromB
FROM A
WHERE A.Date BETWEEN '2000-1-4' AND '2010-1-4'
```

But what is the correct syntax to use multiple columns from a subquery (in my case a select top 1 subquery)? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 157):

Here's generally how to select multiple columns from a subquery:

```
SELECT
     A.SalesOrderID,
     A.OrderDate,
     SQ.Max_Foo,
     SQ.Max_Foo2
FROM
     A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (
     SELECT
          B.SalesOrderID,
          MAX(B.Foo) AS Max_Foo,
          MAX(B.Foo2) AS Max_Foo2
     FROM
          B
     GROUP BY
          B.SalesOrderID
     ) AS SQ ON SQ.SalesOrderID = A.SalesOrderID
```

If what you're ultimately trying to do is get the values from the row with the highest value for Foo (rather than the max of Foo and the max of Foo2 - which is NOT the same thing) then the following will usually work better than a subquery:

```
SELECT
     A.SalesOrderID,
     A.OrderDate,
     B1.Foo,
     B1.Foo2
FROM
     A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B AS B1 ON
     B1.SalesOrderID = A.SalesOrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN B AS B2 ON
     B2.SalesOrderID = A.SalesOrderID AND
     B2.Foo > B1.Foo
WHERE
     B2.SalesOrderID IS NULL
```

You're basically saying, give me the row from B where I can't find any other row from B with the same SalesOrderID and a greater Foo.

Answer (score 42):

```
SELECT a.salesorderid, a.orderdate, s.orderdate, s.salesorderid
FROM A a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT top(1) *
             FROM B b WHERE a.salesorderid = b.salesorderid) as s
WHERE A.Date BETWEEN '2000-1-4' AND '2010-1-4'
```

Comment: This answer works great when the match from B needs to differ for each A record, which doesn't work with a typical subquery join.

Comment: Thank you, outer apply is better than join, because one can reference other parameters as well, which is needed for more complex functions calls etc.

Comment: How to I specify the relationship between the query on A and the apply on B? I would like to select everything from A that is not in B.

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to make a join:

```
SELECT A.SalesOrderID, B.Foo
FROM A
JOIN B bo ON bo.id = (
     SELECT TOP 1 id
     FROM B bi
     WHERE bi.SalesOrderID = a.SalesOrderID
     ORDER BY bi.whatever
     )
WHERE A.Date BETWEEN '2000-1-4' AND '2010-1-4'
```

, assuming that `b.id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` on `B`

In `MS SQL 2005` and higher you may use this syntax:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, Foo
FROM (
  SELECT A.SalesOrderId, B.Foo,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SalesOrderId ORDER BY B.whatever) AS rn
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON B.SalesOrderID = A.SalesOrderID
  WHERE A.Date BETWEEN '2000-1-4' AND '2010-1-4'
) i
WHERE rn
```

This will select exactly one record from `B` for each `SalesOrderId`.

Comment: The first query is clearer. However, if you do a JOIN rather than a LEFT JOIN, if there is no matching record in B, you will lost the record from A. Maybe that's what you want, but it isn't what I'd normally want. Just be aware.

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.*, sq.*
from table1 t1,
   (select a,b,c from table2 ...) sq
where ...
```

Comment: Not only this answer is not explained at all, there is also no relation between the tables. How can this have so many upvotes?

Comment: Please explain what you are doing there, thanks.

Comment: @AugustoMen: See first version. `Shibbz` ruinned the answer

Comment: @AugustoMen because its understandable and it works

Comment: @augustomen I think we can specify the relation in the where clause that is shown below the from clause.