# SQL Server query select 1 from each sub-group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a set of data and need to pull out one record for each CON / OWNER / METHOD / MATRIX set.  If there is a non-null RESULT, I want that one.  Otherwise, I want the one with the highest COUNT.  How do I query this?

```
CON      OWNER      METHOD      MATRIX  RESULT  COUNT
*CON_1   OWNER_1    METHOD_A    SOLID   NULL    503
CON_1    OWNER_1    METHOD_A    SOLID   NULL    1

*CON_1   OWNER_1    METHOD_A    SOIL    NULL    1305
CON_1    OWNER_1    METHOD_A    SOIL    NULL    699

*CON_2   OWNER_2    METHOD_B    SOLID   290     687
CON_2    OWNER_2    METHOD_B    SOLID   NULL    NULL
CON_2    OWNER_2    METHOD_B    SOLID   450     600

CON_2    OWNER_2    METHOD_B    WATER   NULL    1
*CON_2   OWNER_2    METHOD_B    WATER   400     NULL
```

for a result, I would like just the starred records, and I'm showing how each set is grouped.

This is bad SQL:

```
select top (1) CON, OWNER, METHOD, MATRIX, RESULT, COUNT
from #TempTable
group by CON, OWNER, METHOD, MATRIX
order by CON, OWNER, METHOD, MATRIX, COUNT
```

...because my count isn't part of the aggregate function.  Nor does it deal with the RESULT being NULL or not, and top (1) won't return 1 from each grouping.  However, I've not got farther by using a more complex query (such as based on the question at [How can I select multiple columns from a subquery (in SQL Server) that should have one record (select top 1) for each record in the main query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583954/how-can-i-select-multiple-columns-from-a-subquery-in-sql-server-that-should-hav))

How do I select one from each grouping?

Comment: It's hard to choose which to accept, @siva, @Paul Creasey, or @Andrew Lazarus.  All helped.  Andrew's was early and nicely formatted and had the better sorting; Siva's had the T1.Ranking qualifier at the end; and Paul was first and got me going.  I gave an upvote to all, and since Paul's is slightly ahead, I'll accept it.  But all are worthy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this, not 100% sure the syntax is right, but it is close.

```
select 
    * 
from
    (select
        CON,
        OWNER,
        METHOD,
        MATRIX,
        RESULT,
        COUNT,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CON, OWNER, METHOD,MATRIX ORDER BY RESULT,COUNT DESC) as rnk
    FROM #TempTable
) a
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: I have no knowledge that we can write the query in such a way too. Thanks it solves many problems of mine.

Answer (score 2):

In an RDBMS that supports windowing (includes SQL Server 2008, I believe)

```
SELECT CON, OWNER, METHOD, MATRIX, RESULT, `COUNT`
FROM
 (SELECT CON, OWNER, METHOD, MATRIX, RESULT, `COUNT`, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CON, OWNER, METHOD, MATRIX
               ORDER BY RESULT DESC, `COUNT` DESC) AS rk
  FROM temptable
 ) AS s
WHERE rk=1;
```

Note that your text implies only one not-null result per group but your example doesn't. This version will select the maximum result unless all results are the same (e.g., NULL) when `count` will be the tiebreaker. BTW, `COUNT` as a column name is going to cause all sorts of grief. This version also selects multiple rows in case of ties in both result and count. Switch rank to row_number to get only one regardless of whether there is a tie.

Comment: Oh yeah, I shouldn't have used COUNT as a name.  I was anonymizing it, so it didn't have our exact names.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DetailID, field2, field3, field4, MasterID 
from table outer
where DetailID= 
    (
        select max(DetailID) 
        From table inner 
        where outer.MasterID = inner.MasterID
        group by MasterID 
    )
```

You can use it as view and join.