# sql - select multiple values from subquery

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to select multiple values from a subquery in SELECT block?

Selecting one value works fine like this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  (SELECT b.id FROM b WHERE b.a_id = a.id) AS b_id
FROM
  a
```

But if i also want to get the b.name and i change the query to this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  (SELECT b.id, b.name FROM b WHERE b.a_id = a.id)
FROM
  a
```

... it doesn't work anymore. One possibility would be to put the subquery to FROM block and take values from there but in my particular query that doesn't work so i would like to solve in SELECT block. Thank you!

Comment: the subquery should return only one column and one row.

Comment: if you are sure that your subquery returns only one row then write the sub-query twice, once for id and second for name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583954/how-can-i-select-multiple-columns-from-a-subquery-in-sql-server-that-should-ha

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

```
SELECT A.ID,
       B.ID,
       B.NAME
FROM   A INNER JOIN B ON B.A_ID=A.ID;
```

Comment: +1 for using a **JOIN** instead of silly subquery constructs!

Comment: Although the correct way these days is to specify `INNER JOIN` rather than just `JOIN` <removes pedant hat> :)