# mysql: get two values from subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a subquery to retrieve the oldest order for each customer. I want to select `email_address`, `order_id`, and `order_date`

#### Tables:

customers(**customer_id**, email_address)

orders(**order_id**, order_date, customer_id)

#### What I've tried:

I can get either the `order_id` or the `order_date` by doing

```
SELECT email_address, 
       (SELECT order_date /* or order_id */
        FROM orders o
        WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id
        ORDER BY order_date LIMIT 1)
FROM customers c
GROUP BY email_address;
```

but if I try to do `SELECT order_id, order_date` in my subquery, I get the error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: When doing as sub-query like in your example, it has to return one column because it becomes a single column in your results. Simple duplicate the query as another column, and change the column it returns.

Comment: @SloanThrasher that was my initial inclination, but the DRY programmer in me was not satisfied!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a `JOIN`, but you need to be careful to only `JOIN` to the oldest values for a given customer:

```
SELECT c.email_address, o.order_id, o.order_date
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id AND
    o.order_date = (SELECT MIN(order_date) FROM orders o2 WHERE o2.customer_id = c.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN is of your choice.
[How can I select multiple columns from a subquery (in SQL Server) that should have one record (select top 1) for each record in the main query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583954/how-can-i-select-multiple-columns-from-a-subquery-in-sql-server-that-should-ha/584442)

```
SELECT o.order_id, c.email_address, o.order_date
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_date, order_id, customer_id
    FROM orders o
    ORDER BY order_date
) as o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY email_address;
```

Comment: You would need some kind of limit in the JOIN to retrieve only the oldest order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JOIN to get the result you want, or modify your query as below:

```
SELECT email_address, 
    (SELECT order_date
    FROM orders o1
    WHERE o1.customer_id = c.customer_id
    ORDER BY order_date LIMIT 1) as `order_date`,
    (SELECT order_id
    FROM orders o2
    WHERE o2.customer_id = c.customer_id
    ORDER BY order_date LIMIT 1) as `order_id`
FROM customers c
GROUP BY email_address;
```