# Rails: List items by frequency, including the frequency

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

The following will get  one post per category:

```
Post.group(:category_id).order('count *')
```

I could then show a table of representative posts, one per category by listing each result:

```
CATEGORY | SAMPLE POST ID | SAMPLE POST TITLE
        1        |             123           | How to swim out loud
        2        |             246           | On Hamlet
```

However, I'd like to include the count of posts in this category, e.g.:

```
CATEGORY | AMOUNT | SAMPLE POST ID | SAMPLE POST TITLE
        1        |       5       |            123           | How to swim out loud
        2        |       2       |            246           | On Hamlet
```

How can we also show the amount, ie the "count per group"? There's hopefully a way to extract it from the "Post" results as part of an appropriate ActiveRecord query.

Note there's no "Category" table here. category_id is just an independent column. Therefore counter_cache is not a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some sql-magic (the following works with mysql, haven't tested in postgres, but should too):

```
posts = Post.group(:category_id).order('count(*)').select('count(*) as category_cnt, posts.*')
category_count = posts.first.category_cnt
```

Comment: That's it! Very cool that AR supports a dynamic attribute based on the query, thanks 

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `Post` `belongs_to` the `Category`.

That being said, there's an amazing feature in `rails` called `counter_cache`. Check the documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to).

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, dependent: :destroy, counter_cache: true
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  # category should have a column called posts_count
end
```

Now, whenever you create a post, the category's posts_count will increment; when you delete it, it will decrement.

As for your listing, you can do something like:

`Category.order(posts_count: :desc)` and the get `category.posts.first`

Comment: Ever had look on `counter_cache: true` in rails ?

Comment: Actually, no, there's no other table here. I'm just looking for a generic way to do this kind of grouped count query, without counter_cache magic (which I agree is cool when it's possible).

Comment: @mahemoff so you have a `category_id` which is not a relationship to `category` table ?

Comment: Yes, it could be any enum type like "severity level". Even if there was another table, I'd be curious how to do it without memoizing the count, ie directly with a query.

Comment: @mahemoff not sure if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765671/2903313 but it's more like querying and sub-querying tables; and you can then read the result as a hash